# SSIS package gets fatal error while reading the input stream from the network

Tags: sql, sql-server, networking, ssis

**Problem**

When executing a data-heavy SSIS package that inserts the data from a database in `EnvironmentA1` to a database `EnvironmentB1`, I get the following error:

```
A fatal error occurred while reading the input stream from the network. The session will be terminated (input error: 10060, output error: 0)
```

**Context Information**

`EnvironmentA1` - virtual machine in local data center, running SQL Server 2017

`EnvironmentB1` - virtual machine in Azure, running SQL Server 2017

The package is being executed from SSIS Catalog scheduled daily by SQL Agent. Very occasionally it will succeed but it is now generally expected to fail every time it runs, different step every time.

What is really baffling to me about this is that if I set to run the same package interactively in Visual Studio using the exact same connection strings with the same security context for both `EnvironmentA1` & `EnvironmentB1` connection managers it will succeed every time without any issues. The Visual Studio itself is installed elsewhere in `EnvironmentC1`.

This is how example entries in SQL Error Log on `EnvironmentB1` look like around the time of failure:
[image]

Error messages from SSIS Catalog execution report:
[image]

Everything above and the research made suggest that this is network related issue. The common suggestion found was to disable any TCP Offloading related features which I did for both environments but that didn't make any difference.

`EnvironmentA1`:

[image]

`EnvironmentB1`:

[image]

Additionally for testing purposes I disabled the following features from NIC configuration on each environmet:

`EnvironmentA1`:

- Receive-Side Scaling State
- Large Send Offload V2 IPv4
- Large Send Offload V2 IPv6
- TCP Checksum Offload IPv4
- TCP Checksum Offload IPv6

`EnvironmentB1`:

- Receive-Side Scaling
- Large Send Offload Version 2 IPv4
- Large Send Offload Version 2 IPv6
- TCP Checksum Offload IPv4
- TCP Checksum Offload IPv6
- IPSec Offload

Also to note there are other SSIS packages that interact with same both environments and some of them has never produced a similar error, but they are either dealing with insignificant amount of data or pushing it in the opposite direction (`EnvironmentB1` to `EnvironmentA1`)

As a temporary measure I have also tried deploying the package to the SSIS Catalog of `EnvironmentA2` (development version of `EnvironmentA1`) and scheduling execution using production connection strings, but it gets the exact same issue and the only guaranteed way to run the package successfully remains running it via Visual Studio.

If anyone could at least point me in the right direction of diagnosing this issue, that would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if I can add any other info for the context.

Comment: Images of errors really don't help us help you, and they really don't allow users with things like screen readers help you. Take the time to remove the images and replace them with the text from the images.

Comment: When you say `EnvironmentA1` is a virtual machine in a local datacenter... is it vSphere or ESXi? Each guest operating system has very specific vNIC requirements and the default guest configuration seems to have the almost-magical ability to select the wrong one.

Answer (score 0):

Your 3rd SSIS error states the connection was forceably closed by remote host.
That suggests firewall or network filtering issues. Check with your network guys if that could be the case.